# How do I answer someone?

Tags: support, comments

Lets say I want to answer someone and get that person "That Guy" notified. How do I do that? Which of the following options are valid?

> @That Guy: That was a great post, thanks! (1)
>
> @ThatGuy: That was a great post, thanks! (2)
>
> @That Guy : That was a great post, thanks! (3)
>
> @ThatGuy: That was a great post, thanks! (4)

Comment: They'll all work but a comment of that form is likely to be deleted!

Comment: @JosephWright: That was just an example. Btw. I have seen a lot of comments like this, e.g. "+1 Rep for xyz" Please post your answer as an answer, so that I may accept it - getting the formalities right.

Comment: [meta.se] FAQ reference: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168244)